# Can you be disciplined for how a work colleague interprets your communication to them?

Tags: communication, united-kingdom

I have an incident in my workplace whereby a colleague has made a comment to my line manager that they found something I said strange and they could not understand why I asked the question in front of colleagues.

My line manager has taken this and started an informal disciplinary meeting claiming it’s how I said what I said. There are a number of problems I have with this. (1) what is claimed to have been said is different to what was actually said and I have two witnesses backing up my story, however my line manager is not prepared to interview them to get there side of story. (2) I have spoken to the colleague since and she stated she didn’t not want to make a complaint as it appears she got wrong end of the stick. (3) can you be disciplined for how someone interprets what you have said over the phone.

The communication in question was;

“Can I ask a question? When I interviewed you one of your job descriptions was to help the sales teams with Marketing communications. Is that still one of your roles or has your role changed”. The colleague interpreted this as “ when I interviewed you said you would do this role so why aren’t you”.

As I mentioned the other colleagues have given me a statements to me backing my story but my line manager doesn’t want to take these into account.

What are my rights and what can I do?

Comment: Has your line manager explained _why_ they don't want to take your witnesses' story into account?

Comment: All she has said is she does not have to do that at this stage.

Comment: Can your colleague who understood wrong talk to your manager? That would be the first and best step to go.

Comment: Hi Puck. I had an 1hr and 30 min conversation with my colleague and she said she would speak to her. I also asked my colleague whether she would put an email together and send to me , my line manager and HR. My line manager has had that conversation and basically told me to no longer contact her and was asking why I asked her to put something in email. I asked because her statement was different to what my line manager was stating and she was saying she did not want to make a complaint. I did invite my line manager into that call but she declined saying why does she need to be

Comment: In the UK - london

Comment: FWIW I can absolutely understand why your colleague misinterpreted that statement in that way.

Comment: I can see how the colleague could take that question the wrong. What I don't see is how this is severe enough to warrant a disciplinary meeting and what looks to like the beginnings of a full scale investigation. Is there more to this story? Help us understand why this is blowing up.

Comment: Hi Seth. It comes on the back of an incident with a client whom I can’t name. I was informed by one of my Senior Technical Managers that a connection we had with the client was going to be stopped due to it being legacy and as a result we would not support any further upgrades on security. The risk being a potential data breach to client. I held a meeting with a colleague and we decided that we should tell client. We held meeting with client and the senior tech manager was present and we told client. Senior management was then CV’d into minutes of meeting. TBC

Comment: We then hold several meetings with client and each time minutes are sent to senior management. Client then has a data breach which is not related to our business and 5 days after going public asks for clarity on what I said and my recommendation. I replied with an email saying what I had previously stated about concern around data breach and have my recommendation as their account manager. Client complained and where told what I told them is incorrect. Client then stated they did not like fact I was misleading them and trying to sell to them when they just had breach. TBC

Comment: They requested I was removed from account as they could no longer trust me. I was informed in a meeting and showed my senior management evidence that I was told my one of the senior tech managers and that all of them knew about comms as they were all copied into the emails and minutes but took no action till someone realised it was incorrect 1 1/2 months later. Managing Director then wanted to brush under the carpet as his senior team where implicated into what happened. I however have been made the scale goat. She is now bringing this back up in the disciplinary hearing

Comment: What was the context of this question? Figuring out who was responsible to communicate with the client?

Answer (score 3):

> What are my rights and what can I do?

- If you have a union representative, contact them.
- If you have a workers council, contact them.
- If you have a lawyer, contact them.

If all that fails, you could contact HR. Because in the end, HR will write down the reprimand or execute whatever disciplinary action is deemed appropriate and they don't want to be embarrassed later when the "case" blows up. Make sure you go into that meeting knowing fully well, *unlike the three options above, they are not on your side*. They are on the side of whatever solution is the least mess for the company.

If all else fails you could go to your bosses boss and complain. But don't expect too much.

Comment: In other words, you need to convince HR that believing you will be less messy than believing your co-worker and the line manager who isn't investigating properly.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I ask a question? When I interviewed you one of your job
>   descriptions was to help the sales teams with Marketing
>   communications. Is that still one of your roles or has your role
>   changed

Well, if this is done in front of the team it for sure crosses at least two lines which should normally not be crossed, but that is not the matter at hand I suppose. Can you be disciplined if you say this via phone? That probably depends on  the laws of your country, the company rules and culture.

I personally think your manager should give you a clear warning here not to cross the red lines again and clearly explain to you what these are, and explain you your role as a colleague, participant of interview processes and your role in the team (since you don't provide context I have to assume the worst). If that warning is written, or oral is in the eye of the beholder. If a warning is sufficient is related to your past record regarding warning from management.

Comment: What could even be perceived to be wrong with the question OP asked their colleague? As far as I'm interpreting the question they wanted to know if they're still fulfilling a certain role or if someone else is filling that role. I'm assuming they had a request for the person assuming that role and wanted to send the request to the correct person.

Comment: the question asserts the authority to ask for another persons role in a very aggressive way.